# Netmiko: How to search in switch using a variable

Tags: networking, network-programming, netmiko

I am not getting any output if I am doing this.

```
mac_address=abcd
output=net_connect.send_command('show mac-address-table | inc mac_address')
print("Output of the switch  ",output)
```

I am getting the desired output if I am doing this.

```
output=net_connect.send_command('show mac-address-table | inc abcd')
print("Output of the switch  ",output)
```

What should I make change in the code so that I can use variable?

Comment: The closing quote in the first example is after `mac_address`, making that literal text, not a variable.

Comment: ok so what change should I make?

Comment: I'm not sure how you append two strings, but something like: `output=net_connect.send_command('show mac-address-table | inc '+mac_address)` where the `+` is appending the literal string and the variable string.

Comment: It worked! @RonMaupin.  I tried different things and it didn't work. This concatenation didn't click in my mind! Thanks!

Comment: OK. I posted an answer so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closing quote in the first example is after `mac_address`, making that literal text, not a variable. I'm not sure how you append two strings, but something like:

```
output=net_connect.send_command('show mac-address-table | inc '+mac_address)
```

where the `+` is appending the literal string and the variable string.